# Sorbet overrides URI from Kernel

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I have method as below

```
  sig do
    params(uri: URI).returns(String)
  end
  def get(uri)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.start
    response = http.request_get(uri.path)
    response.body
  ensure
    http&.finish
  end
```

Test method is like below (does not use sorbet)

```
def test_get_retry
    uri = URI('http://localhost:4567')
    instance = BookStoreHttpClient.new
    begin
      instance.get_with_retry(uri)
    rescue StandardError
      assert(true)
    end
end
```

But Sorbet complains with "Method `host` does not exist on `URI`", but it is a Kernel class actually.

Is there a way to tell Sorbet to use Kernel::URI instead of URI in `sorbet/rbi/hidden-definitions/hidden.rbi`

Comment: Is it not possibly to simply specify your sig as `params(uri: Kernel::URI)...`?

Comment: Then it complains with "Unable to resolve constant `URI`"

Comment: What makes you think there is a type called `Kernel::URI`? Did you make this class?

Comment: Sorry, it is my wrong interpretation here. I updated the question content, so URI is resolved in the test file, but not in a file sorbet is enabled. When I go to definition URI in the test file it leads me to `uri.rbi` file which has module "Kernel" and URI definition in it.

Comment: `Kernel::URI` is a method, not a type. It returns an instance of `URI::Generic`, `URI::HTTPS`, etc.

Comment: OK that's true. I tried to do `include Kernel` but did not help as well. Not very familiar with Ruby/Sorbet namespacing concepts :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorbet is correct, and the problem is not that it's using the wrong `URI`.

`URI` is not a type, it's a module that contains types: `URI::Generic`, `URI::HTTPS` etc. `Kernel::URI` is also not a type, it's a function that returns an instance of one of the types contained in the `URI` module.

For example:

```
URI("google.com") # => #<URI::Generic google.com>
URI("https://www.google.com") # => #<URI::HTTPS https://www.google.com>
```

You should either specify the type of URI you want, for example:

```
params(uri: URI::HTTPS).returns(String)
```

Or pick a subset and use a union type:

```
params(uri: T.any(URI::HTTP, URI::HTTPS)).returns(String)
```

Comment: Given that `URI::Generic` seems to be the ancestor of all URI::xxx classes OP should be able to use `params(uri: URI::Generic)`

Comment: @radiospiel They *could*, but that doesn't mean it's good advice. OP probably doesn't want to accept, for example, `//foo` or `bar` or `ftp://blah` or `ldap://blah`, all of which are either instances of `URI::Generic`, or a subclass thereof that would be allowed by `params(uri: URI::Generic)`.